# NextJS: Override html lang

Tags: next.js, localization, lang

So I've recently migrated a website from React to NextJs and the website is active in Sweden and Norway with the URLs; domain.com/se and domain.com/no

When we migrated the website we thought it was a good idea to use `se` and `no` as locales.

(next-18next.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
  // https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#logging
  debug: false, //process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    locales: ['default', 'se', 'no'],
  },
  localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales'),
  localeDetection: false,
  reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
};
```

It has worked out very good until now when we realized that Next automatically sets `lang` tag on the `<html>` tag on the page to `se` or `no`, but we want `sv` or `nb`.

And we haven't found a way to override Next.

We've tried to set the lang tag in `_document.tsx` like this:
`<Html lang="sv">...</Html>`
But it only works on the first render(on the server) and then Next overrides this value and sets it to `se`. This means that in the HTML-file that the server returns we get the correct value `<html lang="sv">...</html>`, but then on the client side Next sets it to `se`.

Do you know any way to stop Next from overriding our value or do we need to change the locales to `sv` and `nb` and use [domain routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#domain-routing) or another approach?